# Sort Column of Dataframe by similarity, first row should be fixed Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, similarity

[image]

I want to order the Frame depending on the first row of B. So the first row of B is allways fixed and the second, third .... row is sorted by similarity of B's first row. It should also be flexible, B could contain 2-20 or even more rows

I expect a result like this

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the values by the difference from the first value in `b`, you can just use that index into the original DataFrame:

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6), 'b': [483, 479, 503, 479, 485, 495]})

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   a    b
0  0  483
1  1  479
2  2  503
3  3  479
4  4  485
5  5  495

In [37]: idx = df['b'].sub(df.loc[0, 'b']).abs().sort_values().index

In [38]: df.loc[idx]
Out[38]:
   a    b
0  0  483
4  4  485
1  1  479
3  3  479
5  5  495
2  2  503
```